# Apache Derby Tables, Writing a query that indicates primary and foreign keys in a table

Tags: database, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key, derby

I am new to Apache Derby so this question may seem remedial but I am trying to find a way to write a select statement from the ij prompt that will show all of the fields along with their data types, i.e. CHAR(), VARCHAR(), INT, etc. and indicate whether they are a foreign or primary key.  The only thing I have come across so far is the describe table utility.  That provides some useful information but it does not, as far as I can tell, give any info pertaining to primary and foreign keys.  I'm thinking that I need to be looking in the SYS.SYSCONSTRAINTS table but when I ran a simple select statement on that table the results I got back were critic.  The output that I am hoping to get would be something like this

```
==================================================
FIELD NAME      FIELD TYPE   CONSTRAINTS
==================================================
FIRST NAME      VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL  
LAST NAME       VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL 
MIDDLE INTIAL   CHAR(1)
BIRTH DATE      DATE         NOT NULL
DEPT NUMBER     CHAR(3)      NOT NULL FOREIGN - DEPARTMENT
SSN             CHAR(9)      NOT NULL PRIMARY
```

I assume the answer, if there is one is in joining two or more of the sys. tables but I have not been able to find out which ones.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, the system tables will have all the information, but they can be a bit low-level and take some time to decipher. Another command you can try is the IJ "show" command: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/tools/rtoolsijcomrefshow.html

Comment: Or, use a database browsing tool like SQLSquirrel.

Comment: It looks like the SQL Squirrel may give me what I was looking for under it's metadata section.  I would like to learn how to write the SQL to retrieve that info but this will due nicely for now.  Thank you for your help.